# Word for things that can become outdated

Tags: word-request

I can think of "perishable". However I do not know if I can use it in context of programming. I want to say that the code or a program is replaced when there is a new and better technology.

Edit: I mean code will someday be replaced someday in the future. It is not obsolete right now.

Comment: I think the answers so far are using the wrong tense. The question is asking for words that describe a potential future state of the code. "Deprecated" implies that the code has already become obsolete. The OP wants a word that describes code that, although technically not deprecated now, will likely become that way in the near future.

Comment: @SirBraneDamuj Software that will be obsolete in the future can be described currently as "exists".

Comment: @GalacticCowboy has a point, that most code will be replaced sooner or later. See my answer below, **workaround,** which is a temporary solution to a problem that will permanently be fixed later. I'm a professional programmer myself, so if you give a little more detail about your situation I may have a more technical, specialized word for what you're dealing with

Comment: @emmy Can you please use the [edit] link under your question to tell us whether you mean that the code or program _has been_ replaced or that it  _will someday be replaced_? The answer will determine which term is appropriate. In the first case, _deprecated_ is the correct term.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you just want to say that it is possible for the code to be replaced by something new/faster/better, you could use the adjective ***supersedable***, which means basically "able to be replaced or made obsolete".<sup>1</sup> A more casual, modern way to say the same thing is that the code is ***not*** future-proof.<sup>2</sup>

If you want to talk about how long it will probably be before the code is superseded, then I would use ***half-life***.

The term *half-life* refers to how long it takes for something to undergo some process. It might be most familiar in relation to radioactive decay or drug metabolization.

In the realm of technology it can be used to refer to how long it will be before some new technology makes a product obsolete.<sup>3</sup> So if the code you're talking about will probably be obsolete *soon*, you could say it *has a short half-life*.

---

<sup>1</sup> From [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/supersede):

> **supersede**
>   verb (used with object), **superseded, superseding**.
>
> 1. to replace in power, authority, effectiveness, acceptance, use,
>      etc., as by another person or thing.
> 2. to set aside or cause to be set aside as void, useless, or obsolete, usually in favor of something mentioned; make obsolete:
>      *They superseded the old statute with a new one.*

<sup>2</sup> From [*Techopedia*](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/2204/future-proof):

> **Definition - What does Future Proof mean?**
>   Future proof is a buzzword that describes a product, service or
>   technological system that will not need to be significantly updated as
>   technology advances. In reality, very few things are truly future
>   proof. In any field that depends heavily on technology, a regular
>   cycle of replacing and updating appears to be the norm.

<sup>3</sup> For example:

> [W]hat is the **half life** of your technology devices these days? By that
>   I mean, at what point are you already starting to think about
>   upgrading your devices — from the moment you purchased the last one?
>
> **Half-life** is the moment when you could continue to use your device but
>   it is either so far behind the functionality of other devices or —
>   because of performance issues — it is increasingly unusable. Both
>   points used to take three to five years, but are now more likely to be
>   only one or two years.

—["Why is the half-life of technology getting shorter?" *Global Telecoms Business*, 2012.](http://www.globaltelecomsbusiness.com/article/3102301/Why-is-the-half-life-of-technology-getting-shorter.html#/.WDR3UWorJtQ)

Comment: +1 for **"not future-proof"** as it describes exactly what the OP was asking. Most other answers are about something what is already outdated to begin with. Depending on the context, I would use **"not future-proof enough"**, as to be 100% future-proof is practically impossible.

Answer (score 9):

How about **transient**?

1. not lasting, enduring, or permanent; transitory.
2. lasting only a short time; existing briefly; temporary: 
   *transient authority.*
3. staying only a short time: 
   *the transient guests at a hotel.*

Or **temporal**:

3. enduring for a time only; temporary; transitory

Both definitions from dictionary.com.

Comment: "Temporary" is also a plain word given in both these definitions that means what OP seems to mean. Also, if the replacement of the software is *planned*, then the software is "transitional" -- intended to sure during the duration from one software product to another.

Answer (score 7):

Consider **[fleeting](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/fleeting)**:

1. passing swiftly; vanishing quickly; transient; transitory:
   fleeting beauty; a fleeting glance.

> I would prefer not to use such a fleeting technology on this long-term project.

Saying something like the above would convey that you suspect the technology in question is merely a fad, or not yet mature/stable enough, to consider using it as a long-term solution to a problem.

Comment: "Evanescent" has a very similar meaning.

Answer (score 6):

The software can become **obsolete**; When the software is obsolete, it will be **superseded** by the new technology.

Depending on the context, though, you may not even need to say any of this; software is assumed to be ephemeral and temporary, given the speed of change in the software industry.

Comment: How about **deprecated**?

Comment: @PatrickGregorio **Deprecated** means "insulted" or "belittled". Despite it's similarity to **depreciated**, the two words are distinct and should not be mixed up.

Comment: @Werrf Not sure whether you're suggesting he should use "depreciated" instead, but "deprecated" is commonly used (in the software industry, at least) to refer to something that is obsolete or otherwise should not be used. [The MW definition](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/deprecate) includes "criticize", "disapprove of". By contrast, "depreciate" refers to a reduction in the *value* of something. So something that is deprecated may also have depreciated, but something that depreciates is not necessarily deprecated.

Comment: @Werrf that's if you're using the word in the regular sense. In the software industry, the term **deprecated** means outdated and will soon be obsolete in future versions. Since the OP asked "in the context of programming" I think deprecated is the actual answer here.

Comment: @Werrf Deprecated  is a very common term in in programming.

Answer (score 4):

You could say the program will be [deprecated (Wikipedia explanation)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deprecation).

Comment: Should that not be 'deprecated', rather than 'depreciated'?

Comment: @mike No - *deprecate* generally means 'to express disapproval of', disparage or belittle. *Depreciate* means 'to lose value over time.

Comment: I realise that. However, I'm referring to 'software deprecation' - meaning that its usage is no longer recommended, and that it isn't undergoing further development. 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deprecation

Comment: I've mostly seen "deprecated" applied to functions of past versions, or at most, functions that are not supported in the next version of the software.  In this particular case (where some software is replaced by something better) it would be more common to use "made obsolete".

Comment: Deprecated is a term of art (for example, there are automated systems that will warn when using deprecated interfaces or features) and specifically means that some particular feature is considered legacy and is a candidate for removal.

Answer (score 4):

**Obsolescent** means becoming obsolete. It describes something that is in current use, or can be used now, but which is expected to be obsolete in the future. [See also here](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/obsolescent)

Comment: ...This is the actual answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could say that the program or software becomes *obsolete*.

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/obsolete
Obsolete: no longer used because something newer exists : replaced by something newer

Although it is a general term that can be used to describe a broad spectrum of things that are outdated, it is commonly used to describe technology or software that is outdated. In fact, some software has *built-in* or *planned obsolescence*, where it is purposely designed to have a limited useful lifespan, in order to bring back repeat business by forcing users to upgrade to a newer version.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planned_obsolescence#In_software

Comment: Please [edit] to include an explanation of *why* this is correct; answers without explanation do not teach the patterns of the language well.

Answer (score -1):

I'm sure GalacticCowboy was being sarcastic in his comment, but it's a good point. *Most* software or code will be replaced sooner or later.

If it's some piece of code or feature you're just using now because you have no other options (but possibly will replace or fix when you have the opportunity), try **workaround.**

> **work·a·round**
>   noun (used in computing)`
>   A method for overcoming a problem or limitation in a program or system.

If the code/software is as intended, but will likely get replaced soon after deployment, you can say it has a short **half-life** as in [this answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/110107/42536).